# How to proxy SQL queries made by Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I need to pass any additional info to SQL query made by Django ORM.

For example append to `WHERE` statement more conditions.

```
... <SQL Query> ... WHERE ... AND (True or {request_id});
```

Can I do it without monkey patching `SQLCompiler`, `BaseCommand` etc.?

Comment: Define a custom Manager class.

Comment: It works for only one model. I try to find solution for all models.